# How to create a timer in java

Tags: java, multithreading, time

I want to create a timer, given a set amount of time the user has to answer the question within the allotted time, if he/she fails to do so, the user no longer has the option to enter  the answer

I've tried timer. I need a separate thread to check in if the allotted time is up and then exit the loop.

Comment: Have you tried the class....`Timer` ?

Comment: I'm not voting to close this as a duplicate, but as unclear.  Tamir, you said that you've tried timer, maybe you should elaborate more on your problems?  Why wouldn't Timer do what you needed it to?

Answer (score 0):

By Using [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Stopwatch {
static int interval;
static Timer timer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
    String secs = sc.nextLine();
    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();
    interval = Integer.parseInt(secs);
    System.out.println(secs);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(setInterval());

        }
    }, delay, period);
}

private static final int setInterval() {
    if (interval == 1)
        timer.cancel();
    return --interval;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how that, is supposed to work if i want to put a time limit on an answer.